Transfer max amount of SOL from wallet while accounting for gas fees
This is the current transfer instruction, with amount being the total SOL contained in the fromWallet wallet.
SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: fromWallet,
    toPubkey: toWallet,
    lamports: amount * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL 
});

The problem is, this doesn't work because it transfers the fees too. What's the best way to go about this?

It's a bit annoying, but you can figure out the fee for your transaction using getFeeForMessage https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getfeeformessage and then subtract that from your wallet amount.
The Solana CLI does something similar, so you can see a (Rust) implementation of this idea at: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/9f10f09613c6336eb4b6bbf2cd1fe235378dfb33/cli/src/spend_utils.rs#L145
